# What is the purpose of defining an inner class within a static method?

Tags: java, oop, static, inner-classes

I was reading the book "[Head First Java](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjava/)" and at some point it mentioned that an inner class instance must be tied to an outer class instance, which I was already aware of, but with an exception:

> A very special case—**an inner class defined within a static method**. But
>   you might go your entire Java life without ever encountering one of
>   these.

I'm pretty sure that last statement is indeed true, but if the compiler allows it to happen it means that it exists for a reason, otherwise it would be illegal Java. Can someone show me an example of where this would be useful?

Comment: Can it be an anonymous inner class? Because there are tons of those.

Comment: That's a local class, [JLS #14.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3), not just an inner class.

Comment: @EJP But it *is* an inner class, so a it would meet the criteria of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be special, it may not be.

You're looking at a local class available within a method:

```
class Foo {
    static void bar(){
       class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
           public void run() {
               System.out.println("No longer anonymous!");
           }    
        };
       Thread baz = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
    }

}
```

I've seen uses of inner classes that are anonymous like:

```
class Foo {
    static void bar(){
        Thread baz=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("quux");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is technically an inner class(though anonymous) and defined in a static method. I personally would create a static nested class that implements Runnable and do:

```
baz = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
```

where `MyRunnable` is defined as:

```
class Foo {
    static void bar(){
       // SNIP
    }
    static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("No longer anonymous!");
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: If you move `MyRunnable` inside `bar` you have the exact same scenario that fedeetz is interested in.

Comment: It won't compile, change `static class MyRunnable` to `class MyRunnable`

Comment: @MiserableVariable Sorry, I personally am not proficient with local classes.

Comment: Interesting. I was asking this because I've never got anywhere near _needing_ something like this in any of my projects.

Comment: See my answer, hopefully it explains

Answer (score 1):

Some people take the view that any method that *can* be static *should* be static. To such a person, the inner-beauty of the class would not be terribly relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fabricated example of an inner class within a static method. It can be claimed that

1. It does not need to be declared outside the static method as it is not required elsewhere
2. It should be a named class (i.e. not anonymous) as it is being used multiple times

   ```
   class Race {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
           class Runner implements Runnable {
               final String name;
               long time = -1;
               Runner(String name) { this.name = name; }
               public void run() {
                   try {
                       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                       time = -2;
                       System.out.printf("Start %s\n", name);
                       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                           Thread.sleep(1000);
                       }
                       System.out.printf("End %s\n", name);
                       this.time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       time = -3;
                   }
               }
               long time() { return time; }
           }                
           Runner r1 = new Runner("One");
           Runner r2 = new Runner("Two");
           Thread one = new Thread(r1);
           Thread two = new Thread(r2);
           one.start();
           two.start();
           one.join();
           two.join();
           System.out.printf("One: %s, Two: %s\n", r1.time(), r2.time());
           System.out.printf("%s wins\n", r1.time() < r2.time() ? "one" : "two");
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full context, but closures (i.e. Guava's `Function` implementation) and implementations defined in an utility class could be an example.

However, after searching for a while, I haven't found anonymous closure examples in Guava itself.